# How to hide events that is already past in Solspace Calendar

Tags: solspace-calendar

I use Solspace Calendars for booking of a conference room. Since we do not need to see past bookings, is it possible to hide all past entries so the calendar in month view is not so cluttered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're simply listing events and occurrences in a chronological order and only want to display upcoming events, use {exp:calendar:cal} with the following parameters:

```
{exp:calendar:cal
    pad_short_weeks="n"
    date_range_start="today"
    date_range_end="+1 month" {!-- ...or whatever timeframe in the future --}
}
```

If you're using {exp:calendar:cal} to build a *monthly calendar table*, however, the above would give you a partial calendar table, with some weeks/days missing. In that case, try comparing each event's start date with the {current_time} variable available in EE:

```
{if '{event_start_date format="%U"}' > '{current_time format="%U"}'} Your event data {/if}
```

Some points:

- Be careful of quotes in the above!
- Use the [advanced monthly calendar example](http://www.solspace.com/docs/calendar/month/#examples), or something along those lines. You may be able to pull it off with {exp:calendar:month} as well, but {exp:calendar:cal} is the most thorough and flexible tag.